# Find number that is returning certain reminders if divided by certain number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My employer asked me a question today and I was able to provide the answer using python programming language. I would like to know now what the mathematical equation would look like or at least some pointers on how to calculate it. The question is:

There is less than 300 oranges in the truck. If we put oranges in boxes of 4 we will have 1 orange left, if we put them in boxes of 5 we will have 2 oranges left and if we arrange them in boxes of 6 we will have 3 oranges left. How many oranges can possibly be in the truck?

I have seen few similar questions here but never with so many options. The answers are :
57
117
177
237
297
I can provide the code i used to calculate it but it's irrelevant. I would like some help with writing an equation to calculate it. As i said before .. this isn't a homework. I know that reminder can be expressed as  1 = n - 4a where 1 is reminder, n is the number I'm looking for and a= n-1. 
Am i even on the right track? And how do i go about calculating it for all the options as described above? Is there a way to calculate it other than trying each number in range? All the help appreciated. It's really annoying me now.I guess it's been a while since i went to school.

Comment: Please at least point me on some study materials so I can learn how to solve it. My approach was to make computer iterate by each number in range and return the numbers that are satisfying all the conditions.

Comment: Perhaps look for the "Chinese Remainder Theorem"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of oranges is $\ 4a+1=5b+2=6c+3$

The last equation shows that the number must be divisible by $3$, so we can also write $3d$ instead of $6c+3$

Now, you can use the chinese remainder theorem that shows that the number of oranges modulo $3\cdot4\cdot5=60$ is uniquely determined.

The smallest number of the form $4a+1$ , which is divisible by $3$ , is $9$. So, the number is congruent to $9$ modulo $12$.

The possible numbers are $9,21,33,45,57$. Only the number $57$ is of the form $5b+2$, so the number of oranges is $57+60k$

Since we have less than $300$ oranges , $k$ can have the values $0$ to $4$ corresponding to the numbers you mentioned.

Comment: Great explanation, After reading up on Chinese reminder theorem it all makes sense.